# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'showOpenFilePicker' on 'Window': Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Пытаюсь на внешне сайте с помощью tampermonkey запис та  определенный данные на свой файл, при подключении
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_getValue
моя функция для открытия и сохранения файла не работает.

```
if (document.getElementById('billNo')){
            const para = document.createElement("button");
            para.innerHTML = '<button class="btn-primary non-disabled-btn tsBtnCss" type="button" id= "read"> <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>UP</button>'+
                '<button class="btn-primary non-disabled-btn tsBtnCss" type="button" id= "save"> <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Down</button>'
            document.getElementsByClassName("f1")[0].appendChild(para);

            let fileHandle;
            let fileData;
            let text

            async function read(){
                [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker()
                fileData = await fileHandle.getFile();
                text = await fileData.text();
            }

            async function save(){

                let stream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
                var val= getValues();
                await stream.write(text+"\n"+val);
                await stream.close();
            }

            document.getElementById("read").addEventListener("click",read)
            document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click",save)
        }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пытаюсь на внешнем сайте с помощью tampermonkey записать определенный данные с сайта  на свой файл, запросе на открыть файл выдает ошибку Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'showOpenFilePicker' on 'Window': Illegal invocation
    at HTMLButtonElement.read